# To publish Audit Log Daily

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, auditing, audit-log-reports

I tried to publish Audit Log Reports every day using "Site collection audit settings".
I configured as below  in 2 site collections.
Also, I attached config image too.
1 site collection could publish audit report to target document library however, the other site collection could not.
Is there any clue to publish audit log repot in this site collection?

Automatically trim the audit log for this site?  >>Yes  
Optionally, specify the number of days of audit log data to retain:  >>90

If you'd like to keep audit data for longer than this, please specify a document library where we can store audit reports before trimming occurs: >> Enter Site/Library URL

Specify the events to audit: >> Check all options

Specify the events to audit: >> Check all options

[image]

Comment: I don’t see an attached picture.

Comment: Dear A.k.A. Fritz 
Thank you for your comment and it was unable to attach picture from my pc.
Instead, I type current configuration.

Comment: So attach the image? Whether or not you do so will determine the value of this post.

Comment: I retried to attach the image.
Is it possible to see now?

Comment: yes it is possible.  I will examine shortly

Answer (score 0):

Whether these two site collections in one web application?

Here're steps about how to configure audit logs, you could check.

You can view audit log reports to ensure who and when clicks individual files. Here are steps as follows:

1.Go to Central Administration -> Manage service applications -> Select Secure Store Service application, and click the properties from the ribbon -> Enable audit and set the number of days to keep audit logs until be purged.

2.Go to sites settings page -> Site Collection Features -> Activate Reporting feature.

3.Go to sites settings page -> Click the Site collection audit settings -> configure the audit log settings.

4.Go to sites settings page -> Click the Audit log reports -> Click content viewing report, you also can click custom reports to custom your content viewing report.